# How to hide mouse cursor?

Tags: autohotkey

How to toggle mouse cursor visibility? Hiding mouse cursor would be useful in particular with certain video players and PC games, when it isn't done automatically.

Comment: Superuser is not a script writing service. Tell us what you have tried and where you are confused.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: Perhaps I haven't grasped what the scope of superuser.com is, but I consider my question as a general "How to hide mouse cursor with this application?" inquiry. I admit that my research has been inadequate, the answer might have been posted on autohotkey.com forums.

Comment: Editing your question to MAKE it as you see it may avoid some of the close votes. While you think your question is "how to hide...", what you've actually written is "I'm requesting a script..." which will nearly always get close-vote criticism for the reasons noted. Make use of the EDIT button, and make your question be what you perceive it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution from the great AHK forums. https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=36693#p36693

```
detectHiddenWindows, On
gui +hwndgHwnd
gui,show,hide w1 h1
winset,transparent,1,ahk_id %gHwnd%
gui +alwaysOnTop +toolWindow -caption +0x80000000
return

ScrollLock::
while(a_timeidlephysical>300000) ; 5-minutes
    sleep 100
tog:=!tog
if(tog){
    blockinput,mousemove
    dllcall("ShowCursor","uint",0)
    mousegetpos,mx,my,active
    gui +Owner%active%
    gui,show,x%mx% y%my% noactivate
} else {
    blockinput,mousemoveoff
    gui,cancel
    dllcall("ShowCursor","uint",1)
}
return
```

Search [here](https://autohotkey.com/search/) for any AHK resources. Of course, i recommend you learn the language further. :)

Comment: Please post the solution, not just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, adapted from that of derz00, (Thanks, that was very useful in my application)

It is, again, an autohotkey script.

However, I've made some key changes.
That script uses the same key to hide and show the mouse whereas mine uses '[' and ']' to hide and show respectively so that I can be specific about which action is taken at any given time without knowing the current state (Don't ask why, I just needed it.)

it also allows the mouse to be moved whilst hidden and does away with the feature whereby the script doesn't respond if the user's input has been idle for too long.

```
gui +hwndgHwnd
gui,show,hide w1 h1
winset,transparent,1,ahk_id %gHwnd%
gui +alwaysOnTop +toolWindow -caption +0x80000000
return


:*:]::
{
    sleep 5
    gui,cancel
    dllcall("ShowCursor","uint",1)
    return
}

:*:[::
{    
    sleep 5
    dllcall("ShowCursor","uint",0)
    mousegetpos,mx,my,active
    gui +Owner%active%
    gui,show,x%mx% y%my% noactivate
    return
}
```

Comment: For your information -- I'll (try to remember to) test your script when I get back to Windows.